# Can't access content in secondary drive partition after installing Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, partition-recovery

I'm going through this problem for some time now, bit more than a month.

I am not a Linux user, I was installing it to learn it. I have two HD's in my note, I had Windows installed in a SSD and used a HDD for backups.

It all started when I tried installing Manjaro Linux in my note. I installed it, grub was set as the boot loader and everything seemed to be fine, but when I tried to boot Windows it didn't boot. I tried to do everything I could find in the web to recover it, at no avail, so I had to create a recovery media and reinstall it from scratch. I did it formatting only the partition in my main SSD drive where the older installation of Windows was installed. After installing it, when I tried to boot Manjaro again I got an error:

[Error shown when trying to load Manjaro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c7zy.jpg)

I gave up Manjaro and tried to set up my hardware under Windows. My drivers are stored in drive D partition 1 of 226GB as shown in the image:

[All my storage drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llYDc.png)

But when I tried to access it through Windows it's shown as an empty drive in Windows Explorer:

[Drive D shown as empty in Windows Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk68R.png)

I really need to access the stuff in this partition and I'm clueless of how to fix this.
If someone can help me to solve this I will be very grateful.

Thanks.

Edit: When I right click Disk 1 Partition 1 in Disk Management Tool all options are grayed out like so:

[Disk Management grayed out options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMJ9M.png)

The drive I desperately need to access is Disk 1 Partition 1.

Answer (score 0):

In your image, it looks like the drive mounted as *D:* is just a 1 GB partition on (physical) Disk 0, and the 226.66 GB partition on Disk 1 **is not mounted**.

In *diskmgmt.msc*,

- Right-click the existing 1 GB D: drive.
- Select *Change Drive Letter and Path...*
- In the dialog, select *Remove* (you probably don't need to view that partition), or *Change...* and select another letter, e.g. *F:*.
- Right-click the 226 GB partition in Disk 1.
- Select *Change Drive Letter and Path...*
- In the dialog, select *Change...* and set it to *D:*.
  [image: Mount as D:]

If the partition cannot be mounted as a drive using Windows *diskmgmt.msc*, try a third-party tool such as free [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/). Open *DiskGenius*, right-click the partition, and select *Assign New Drive Letter*. However, if that option is grayed-out, then even *DiskGenius* could not mount it.

Comment: Ok, I think I messed up with my explanation. The drive I'm trying to access is Disk 1 Partition 1 like in the image. Drive D is an EFI content partition and I can access it. When I right click Disk 1 Partition 1, all options are grayed out, except option "Delete Volume". I'll upload a screenshot to show that.

Comment: @Marvin, if diskmgmt.msc fails to work, then I've added a suggestion in the answer for a third-party tool. Please let me know if that works, here.

Comment: Thank you have much for your help. I appreciate it with all my heart. It seems that I screwed the partition I'm looking for when I installed Linux and the files are gone. I can't find it in the drive just the Linux file system.